# Can I open Explorer at the current path when working in Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

Sometimes I run some commands in the Command Prompt (cmd) on Windows, i.e. for compiling. And it would be handy if I could open Explorer at the current path with a command.

If it is possible, how can I start Explorer at the current path from command prompt on Windows?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like this:

```
explorer .
```

The period being used to represent the current folder. Single one meaning this folder, Two of them, being the next folder up the hierarchy.

If at C:\Users\Bonzo...

```
explorer .
```

Opens up the folder C:\Users\Bonzo

```
explorer ..
```

Opens up the folder C:\Users, and

```
explorer ..\..
```

Opens up C:\

The dots work also with the cd command and pretty much anywhere else you need to specify locations.

Comment: even shorter, on Windows 7 and Windows XP and before (seem to recall in broke in Vista): "start ." Less typing.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell:

```
Invoke-Item $Pwd
```